# Rave Reports Delphi Seattle

Tags: delphi-7, componentes

Qual a real função do componente Rave Reports no Delphi?
E onde é possível baixar esse componente gratuitamente. 
Pois tenho uma aplicação que foi desenvolvida em Delphi 7 que esta utilizando este componente e preciso abrir e executar essa aplicação no Seattle porém da erro neste componente quando tento compilar a aplicação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O **rave reports** é um componente criado para o delphi pela nevrona, que permite criar formulários em runtime.
Antes do fast reports (componente da própria Embarcadeiro) era necessário usar o rave reports para gerar formulários com dados vinculados ao Database, variáveis, inputs do usuário  ou dados criados em tempo de execução.

Após algum tempo com a popularidade do Rave reports a Embarcadeiro decidiu criar seu próprio componente para fazer esse trabalho (fast reports), porém ele não é compatível com todas as versões de Delphi e cpp, então até hoje esse componente usado devido a facilidade de interação com ele e sua retrocompatibilidade.